# Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc #198

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, coredns

I got this error coredns pod doenst start

I deploy kubernetes cluster!

1 pod got status: ContainerCreating

The other one got status Running

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces NAMESPACE NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE kube-system calico-kube-controllers-6d57b44787-xlj89 1/1 Running 15 10d kube-system calico-node-dwm47 1/1 Running 310 5d3h kube-system calico-node-hhgzk 1/1 Running 13 10d kube-system calico-node-tk4mp 1/1 Running 309 5d3h kube-system calico-node-w7zvs 1/1 Running 311 5d3h kube-system coredns-74c9d4d795-psf2v 1/1 Running 0 4d4h **kube-system coredns-74c9d4d795-xpbsd 0/1 ContainerCreating** 0 5d3h kube-system dns-autoscaler-7d95989447-7kqsn 1/1 Running 8 10d kube-system kube-apiserver-master 1/1 Running 1 10d kube-system kube-controller-manager-master 1/1 Running 1 10d kube-system kube-proxy-9bt8m 1/1 Running 1 5d3h kube-system kube-proxy-cbrcl 1/1 Running 2 5d3h kube-system kube-proxy-stj5g 1/1 Running 0 5d3h kube-system kube-proxy-zql86 1/1 Running 0 5d3h kube-system kube-scheduler-master 1/1 Running 1 10d kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-7c547b4c64-6skc7 1/1 Running 589 10d kube-system nginx-proxy-worker1 1/1 Running 1 5d3h kube-system nginx-proxy-worker2 1/1 Running 0 5d3h kube-system nginx-proxy-worker3 1/1 Running 0 5d3h kube-system nodelocaldns-6t92x 1/1 Running 1 5d3h kube-system nodelocaldns-kgm4t 1/1 Running 0 5d3h kube-system nodelocaldns-xl8zg 1/1 Running 0 5d3h kube-system nodelocaldns-xwlwk 1/1 Running 10 10d
```

OS:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7
```

my inventory:

```
master ansible_host=ip ansible_user=root
worker1 ansible_host=ip ansible_user=root
worker2 ansible_host=ip ansible_user=root
worker3 ansible_host=ip ansible_user=root
#[all:vars]
#ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3

[kube-master]
master

[kube-node]
worker1
worker2
worker3

[etcd]
master

[calico-rr]

[k8s-cluster:children]
kube-master
kube-node
```

My Problem Pod Log:

```
Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "coredns-74c9d4d795-xpbsd": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:303: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\"": unknown
1
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me which kernel version of centos and which version of docker you use? I found similar problem as yours [there](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/docker-error-response-from-daemon-1d46235ff61d). Let me know if that help somehow.

Comment: docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.39 (downgraded from 1.40)
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:28:55 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Jun 27 17:26:28 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

Comment: uname -a
Linux worker1 3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 5 14:26:44 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Docker version is fine so i guess you should upgrade your centos kernel, [there](https://www.tecmint.com/install-upgrade-kernel-version-in-centos-7/) you can read how to do it. Let me know if error still exist after upgrade.

Comment: Its risky to update kernel :-)